# Fill preformatted text file to send email - MessageFormat alternative

Tags: java, spring, messageformat

I Used [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) to format the contents of a file with parameters and get so a formated string with correct parameters.
(I used it to format email body.finally I had one file per email body, the application needs to send a lot of different emails, so I got a lot of preformatted body files)

So far, I had six parameters.

Problem: Things are changing and now I have more than 6 parameters today ....

I realize that MessageFormat is limited to 6 parameters!

What can I do? Is there an alternative to MessageFormat? or the only solution is to put each email line in properties ( and hope not to have more than 6 per line parameters !)
Thanks,
Christophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you've tagged this as 'spring' you could use the Apache Velocity templating engine (VelocityEngineFactoryBean), wire it into your class as a VelocityEngine.

You could then use VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString() passing the name of the template file (stored in your classpath)

Comment: Both answers are right ! As I work with Spring, I get a quick result with velocity, with the help of spring documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mail.html - thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use a templating library. [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) for example.